# Postgresql: Execute query every 12 midnight

Tags: postgresql

Im using the latest postgres version and im new with it. I just want to know how can i have an insert query statement that triggers every midnight or using now()::time = '23:59:59'? is it possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgres doesn't have anything out of the box to do what you need. You'll need something like `pg_cron` to allow you to schedule queries:

https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron

Or schedule the query using `psql` via the system's `cron` scheduler.

Comment: sir, one more thing, our company is using RDS which is not supported by the link above. So, does it mean that i cant use it on amazon RDS?

Comment: @itTech If you're using RDS, you'll probably have to create a simple Lambda function and execute that on a schedule.